# Apex regex to validate the Salesforce dot notation

Tags: apex, fields, regular-expressions

In Apex we can access a field using the dot notation

Example : `Owner.Name`

I am looking for a regex to validate that notation

I come up we the regex below

```
String validateDotNotation='([a-zA-Z]([a-zA-Z1-9]|[a-zA-Z1-9]_[a-zA-Z1-9])*[a-zA-Z1-9](__[rRcC])?\\.)*([a-zA-Z]([a-zA-Z1-9]|[a-zA-Z1-9]_[a-zA-Z1-9])*[a-zA-Z1-9](__[cC])?)'
```

Some explanations

```
[a-zA-Z] : validate the first char must be alphabetic upper or lower case
[a-zA-Z1-9] : validate char must be alphanumeric 
[a-zA-Z1-9]_[a-zA-Z1-9] : validate _ must not be two consecutive _
[a-zA-Z1-9]|[a-zA-Z1-9]_[a-zA-Z1-9] : validate middle field name chars can be alphanumeric & non consecutive _
[a-zA-Z]([a-zA-Z1-9]|[a-zA-Z1-9]_[a-zA-Z1-9])*[a-zA-Z1-9] : validate a field name
(__[rRcC])? : custom or relationship field ending 
(__[cC])? : custom field ending
```

Salesforce naming rules for a **field API Name**

[image: Naming rules]

Can you tell me if it's correct or if there is a better way to do it **?**

Comment: Is this the field label or the API name?

Comment: @MartinLezer API Name

Comment: What about custom __r / __c?

Comment: @kurunve thanks just thought about that I'll update the regex

Comment: Personally I would do that as a trigger, so I can confirm that field/path exists and valid by dynamic query, but that may be not that lightweight
(Sorry, thought that validation rule is being used)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems."
>
> -Jamie Zawinski

Regular expressions do have their uses, but I find myself trying to avoid using regex if I can.

I think there's a better solution in your case.

Using Apex, you can pull the fields from an object (any sObject).

```
Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> M = Schema.SObjectType.Account.fields.getMap();
```

Using this approach, you can do something that your regex will never be able to, *you can verify that the given field name is actually a field on your target object*. Given the line of code above, and assuming you have a variable called `fieldName`...

```
if(!M.keySet().containsKey(fieldName)){
    // add an error to be displayed on your Visualforce page here
}
```

It gets a bit more involved if you want to do this for related fields, but using `String.split('.')`, `Schema.getGlobalDescribe()`, and `Schema.DescribeFieldResult.getReferenceTo()`, would accomplish what you're looking to do here.

Answer (score 1):

Field validation

```
/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*(_[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*(__[cC])?$/
```

Reference validation

```
/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*(_[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*(__[rRcC])?$/
```

Explanation

```
[a-zA-Z] : Validate the first char must be alphabetic upper or lower case
[a-zA-Z0-9]* : Following the first char can be any amount of alphanumeric characters
(_[a-zA-Z0-9]+)* : If we have an underscore must be followed by at least one alphanumeric character
(__[rRcC])? : custom or relationship field ending optional (? = matches none or one time)
(__[cC])? : custom field ending (? = matches none or one time)
```

The issue with your expression

```
String validateDotNotation='([a-zA-Z]([a-zA-Z1-9]|[a-zA-Z1-9]_[a-zA-Z1-9])*[a-zA-Z1-9](__[rRcC])?\\.)*([a-zA-Z]([a-zA-Z1-9]|[a-zA-Z1-9]_[a-zA-Z1-9])*[a-zA-Z1-9](__[cC])?)'
```

Is that you can't have only one char before the first char, like `a_b__c`, or `a__c`.
And can't have only a char at the end following an underscore like `hello_f__c`
And that you are leaving 0 out with 1-9

Comment: Please add some explanation if these expressions actually answer the question.